# Characteristic equation for a particular recursion

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Can we find out a characteristic equation for the recursion ----------

$ a_{n+2}=a_n \cdot (a_{n+1}+1)$ for $n \geq 0$ .

where $a_0=a$  ,$a_1=b$

EDIT: @dxiv correctly points out that since this is not a linear recurrence, hence the characteristic equation does not exist. But how do I solve the recurrence if there is no characteristic equation?

Comment: That's not a *linear* recurrence, so there is no characteristic function attached to it.

Comment: Some general formula for the nth term ?

Comment: Some context would help. Are you looking for a nice closed form (and have reasons to believe one exists at all), or asymptotic behavior, or ...?